# Sonata : how to create a 404 error template?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I can't a create working 404 custom error page in production environment, with Sonata `4.13` and Symfony `5.4`.

The official [Sonata documentation](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataPageBundle/en/3.x/reference/error_pages/) didn't help me, so I followed the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/controller/error_pages.html). I created a file in `/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig` with the following content:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Erreur 404
{% endblock %}

{% block sonata_admin_content %}
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body">
        <h1>404 - Page introuvable</h1>
        <p>La page que vous recherchez n'existe pas.</p>
        <p>Vous pouvez <a href="{{ path('home') }}">revenir au Dashboard</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This page displays correctly when I access `localhost/_error/404`, but the sidebar is empty. When I test on the production environment, the same thing happens.

On this 404 error page, I notice that I'm not logged in (my username is not displayed), unlike on the other pages. Maybe the problem is coming from here?

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you turn off `APP_DEBUG`?

Comment: I've tried it in `DEV` and `PROD` mode, and the 404 page behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's expected behavior while having no active session. Probably the menu gets rendered only while you're logged in. If you think this is a bug, please consider raising a bug issue https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle and provide a reproducer repo.

Comment: The menu is only rendered if I'm logged in. But I'm correctly logged in, except on 404 pages where I don't see my session in the debug bar. That's probably where the problem lies. Maybe I haven't included or extended a necessary template?
I'll take the time to report an issue as advised. Thanks a lot!